# How to set the id for a bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown wrapper in typoscript

Tags: navbar, typoscript, submenu

I want to use the id id from a Bootstrap 4 dropdown on its belonging div container like this:

```
<a href="#" id="dropdownXXX" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 
<span class="caret"></span></a>

<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownXXX">

<a href="index.php?id=130" class="nav-link">lalala</a>
<a href="index.php?id=131" class="nav-link">lalalala</a>
<a href="index.php?id=132" class="nav-link">lalalalala</a>
</div>
```

My Typoscript looks like this:

```
lib.mainnav = COA
lib.mainnav{
    10 = HMENU
    10{

        wrap = <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">|</ul>
        1 = TMENU
        1{
            expAll = 1

            NO = 1
            NO{
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="nav-item">|</li>
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                ATagParams = class="nav-link"
            }

            CUR < .NO
            CUR{
               wrapItemAndSub = <li class="nav-item active">|</li>
                ATagParams = class="nav-link"
                stdWrap.noTrimWrap = || <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>|
            }

            IFSUB < .NO
            IFSUB{

                wrapItemAndSub  = <li class="nav-item dropdown">|</li>
                ATagParams =  id="dropdown{field:uid}" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                ATagParams.insertData = 1
                stdWrap.noTrimWrap = || <span class="caret"></span>|
            }

            ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
            ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown active">|</li>

            CURIFSUB < .ACTIFSUB

        }
        2 = TMENU
        2{
            wrap = <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="{HOW TO REUSE THE ID HERE}">
            NO = 1
            NO{
                allWrap = <a class="dropdown-item">|</a>

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone show me how to reuse the id in the wrapper for the submenu items?
my reference is this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using this attempt.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#using-dropdowns

It does not have this caviat.